# How to restrict a new window to open with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a livechat link on clicking that link it opens a new window. I need to redirect that link to contact us page of website when there are no operators online.
I have used this , it first opens the chat window for less than 2 seconds but i need that it should not open that chat window at all. How can I do that?

```
window.opener.location.replace('http://mywebsite.local/index.php?route=information/contact');
window.close();
```

Comment: You need to implement your logic to look for operators online availability and based on that either redirect or open new window.

Comment: `if (operatorsOnline) { url = "live-chat"; } else { url = "contact-page"; }  //redirect to url` - Change the url based on whether or not there are available operators.

Comment: I have used the login and put this in conditions window.opener.location.replace('http://mywebsite.local/index.php?route=information/contact');
window.close();

Comment: the conditions to check if operators are online or not are working fine, problem is that it first opens the chat window and that windows appears for 2 seconds with this code as i have used window.open() for it,

Comment: I want is that it should not open the chat window at all

Comment: What we are suggesting is that you check for the operators *before* you pop open anything. The logic shouldn't be "Pop open this window, check if there's operators, and then close the window." - It should be "If there are available operators, open the window."